# JavaScript EventSource listening for a Webhook pushed to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, eventsource

I've been searching and experimenting and I just can't seem to figure this out. I would appreciate any insight. Thank you!

So I have a Shopify store and I have an Webhook that triggers when I make a sale, meaning it pushes JSON data of that sale to a PHP script on my server. Right now I'm having that PHP script insert the relevant data into a database and mark that sale as "unread." Then, I would have a separate HTML/JavaScript page that I would run separately, polling the server to check for unread sales ever 10 seconds or so. There's a little more to that, but that's the general idea. It's clunky and I would like to modernize this.

Here's what I've been trying and can't seem to get working.

1. Set up an EventSource page that's listening to a separate PHP script.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sales Notification!</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="widget">
        <div id="notification_box"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (!!window.EventSource) {
            var source = new EventSource('alert_listener.php');
        } else {
                console.log("Window.EventSource fail!");
        }

        source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        }, false);

        source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
            // Connection was opened.
        }, false);

        source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
            if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                // Connection was closed.
            }
        }, false);
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

That actually works well when I do something simple like [this example](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/). Anyway, here's my PHP code listening for the JSON sent from the Websocket (some of this code is provided by Shopify):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

error_reporting(0);
define('SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET', 'NOT_PUBLIC_HAR_HAR');

function verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header) {
  $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET, true));
  return ($hmac_header == $calculated_hmac);
}

function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
$hmac_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256'];
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$verified = verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header);
while (1) {
    if ($data !== "") {
        sendMsg("test id", "Data: " . $data);
    }
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

When I push data from Shopify to this PHP script, the first JavaScript example is supposed to be listening for this data, but nothing happens. Not a thing. I have no idea why. I have no idea how to tell the PHP script to say, "Hey! An order came in! Yo JavaScript, do something!" and then the JavaScript go, "New order received! Let's do a thing!"

TLDR:

1. Shopify pushes JSON to a PHP script (via a webhook)
2. Separate JavaScript file listens to this PHP script via EventSource object and reacts accordingly
3. I can't get this to work. Please help.

That is all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on Twitter - and no, this can be answered.

First of I have to admit that I am not familiar all too well with EventSource - but from what I see, you are using exactly one script to do two things at once; obtaining the Shopify data and immediately exporting it to JS. However, each PHP script ran has exactly one request and response context - and in this case, you have been echo'ing your data all the way back to Shopify.

You will need two endpoints:

1. The first endpoint acts as the receipient to Shopify's webhooks (`shopify_webhook.php`). Each time it receives data, you might store it in a database for fire-and-forget actions like Redis, where you set a possibly low TTL. As far as I know, Redis also has queues - so this would probably be a better approach.
2. The second endpoint is your event source that keeps streaming incoming queue entries to your requesting JavaScript (i.e. `shopify_eventsource.php`).

Redis here is just a suggestion - but one way or another, you will have to use an intermediate storage to be able to move the incoming data to another output channel. You can write all this in one PHP file where you validate the incoming request to see if it is a Shopify request (and stream) or if it is your JavaScript code requesting the output. But using two endpoints and thus separating code might make it more readable and adjustable should Shopify change APIs or you your own JavaScript receipient.

TL;DR:

1. `Shopify -> Your endpoint -> intermediate storage.`
2. `Intermediate storage -> your endpoint -(stream)> your javascript.`

Comment: Actually, you might see the term "stream consumer" being used instead of receipient...Well, that was me being sleepy and not being a native speaker using "partially" wrong words. Its not incorrect, but I thought i'd tack it on as a FYI.